# Run skipped tests by nosetest (no-skip doesn't work)

Tags: python, nose, python-unittest

I have a lot of legacy test like this. Tests are skipped with unittest but are run with nosetests.

```
import unittest
import nose
import time


class BaseTestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.skip("Skipped")
    def test_add(self):
        """Test 1"""
        print "Execute test 1"
        time.sleep(5)

    def test_sub(self):
        """Test 2"""
        print "Execute test 2"
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nose.run(argv=["nose", ".", "--verbosity=2", "--nocapture", '--no-skip'])
```

I want to run all skipped tests.
Looks like "no-skip" - option not works, become I have output

```
Execute test 2
Test 1 ... Test 2 ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 5.001s

OK
```

looks like test is present in output but doesn't execute code inside.

I expected to see:

```
Test 1 ... ok
Execute test 1
Test 2 ... ok
Execute test 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 10 s

OK
```

Comment: `--no-skip` seems to be broken https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/889

Comment: Works for me (nose-1.3.7-3)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem, and after some research the issue seems to be that `--no-skip` does not have anything to do with `unittests.skip` but with the handling the exception `nose.SkipTest`.

I ended up with a hacky solution that does the job in my case. Maybe it can help somebody. It consists of using your own custom `skip` function so that it "piggybacks" the `--no-skip` flag and reacts accordingly.

```
import sys
import unittest

no_skip_mode = '--no-skip' in sys.argv

def skip(reason):
    if no_skip_mode:
        # Don't decorate the test function. Just return as is.
        def dummy_wrapper(fn):
            return fn

        return dummy_wrapper

    return unittest.skip(reason)
```

I guess you could try to monkeypatch `unittest.skip`.